# Optimize Multiple Taxonomy Term MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, query, optimization

*(**Moderator's note:** Title was originally: "query/database optimisation")*

I'm written a function for a custom "filter" search panel that allows users to select terms from up to four custom taxonomies. I'm running the queries directly against the database and the query is averaging half a second to execute (with terms for all four taxonomies and one result returned).

This seems pretty slow to me. I was wondering if there's anything I can do to either optimise the query or even the database to make this more efficient/faster. Perhaps writing a view, even? I have experience with MS-SQL but not much with MySQL and I'm not sure how things are different.

Here's my function code:

```
    function filter_resources($phase,$wa,$aus,$topics){
    global $wpdb;
    $querystr="
    SELECT * 
        FROM $wpdb->posts A
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships B ON(A.ID = B.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy C ON(B.term_taxonomy_id = C.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms D ON(C.term_id = D.term_id)

        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships BB ON(A.ID = BB.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy CC ON(BB.term_taxonomy_id = CC.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms DD ON(CC.term_id = DD.term_id)

        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships BBB ON(A.ID = BBB.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy CCC ON(BBB.term_taxonomy_id = CCC.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms DDD ON(CCC.term_id = DDD.term_id)

        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships BBBB ON(A.ID = BBBB.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy CCCC ON(BBBB.term_taxonomy_id = CCCC.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms DDDD ON(CCCC.term_id = DDDD.term_id)

        WHERE A.post_type = 'resources' 
            AND A.post_status = 'publish'
            AND C.taxonomy = 'phase-of-learning'
            AND D.term_id = '$phase'
            AND CC.taxonomy = 'wa-curriculum'
            AND DD.term_id = '$wa'
            AND CCC.taxonomy = 'australian-curriculum'
            AND DDD.term_id = '$aus'
            AND CCCC.taxonomy = 'topics'
            AND DDDD.term_id = '$topics'
        ORDER BY A.post_date DESC";
    return $wpdb->get_results($querystr,OBJECT);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: And before anyone points it out, I have modified the function to account for any combination of the four taxonomies being passed, but that version is longer and the extra conditionals don't add any additional clarity... :)

Comment: Can I assume you that your query only needs `SELECT $wpdb->posts.*` and not  `SELECT *`?  Also, you are using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` yet your `WHERE` clause makes your choice of `LEFT JOIN' moot. Can I confirm that was intentional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is really a MySQL question it does help to understand the WordPress SQL schema and also I love trying to optimize SQL queries so rather than send you off to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) I'll try to answer you here.  You may still want to post it over there to get some other opinions.

And while I don't fully understand your requirement I think I understand what you are asking I think I do so I'd like to present the following to see if it meets your needs better. I don't have your data so it is a little hard for me to very that it indeed works but like I said, I think it meets your needs:

```
function filter_resources($phase,$wa,$aus,$topics){
  global $wpdb;
  $sql =<<<SQL
SELECT
  t.slug,p.*
FROM
  wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID=tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND p.post_type = 'resources'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND t.term_id IN (%d,%d,%d,%d)
  AND CONCAT(tt.taxonomy,'/',t.term_id) IN (
    'phase-of-learning/%s',
    'wa-curriculum/%s',
    'australian-curriculum/%s',
    'topics/%s'
  )
GROUP BY
  p.ID
HAVING
  COUNT(*)=4
ORDER BY
  p.post_date DESC
SQL;
  $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,
    $phase,$wa,$aus,$topics,  // For the %d replacements
    $phase,$wa,$aus,$topics   // For the %s replacements
  );
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT);
  return $results;
}
```

Basically this gives you all posts where all of your taxonomy terms are applied and it does so by doing a freeform query to match all posts that have the taxonomy/terms applied but limits to only those posts that have all terms applied grouping by `wp_post.ID` and finding all records for which the post is joined 4 times. When you run a MySQL `EXPLAIN` the optimization looks pretty good compared to what you had; many fewer tables joined. Hopefully this was the logic you needed.

#### Caching with the Transients API

And if you are trying to improve performance you might also consider caching the results in a *"transient"* for a limited amount of time *(1 hour, 4 hours, 12 hours or more?)* This blog post describes how to use the WordPress [**Transients API**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API):

- [**Overview of WordPress’ Transients API**](http://planetozh.com/blog/2010/05/overview-of-wordpress-transients-api/)

Here's the basic logic for transients:

```
define('NUM_HOURS',4); // Time to cache set for your use case
$data = get_transient( 'your_transient_key' );
if( !$data ) {
  $data = // Do something to get your data here
  set_transient( 'your_transient_key', $data, 60 * 60 * NUM_HOURS );
}
```

To use transients in your `filter_resources()` function it might instead look like this:

```
define('RESOURCE_CACHE_HOURS',4);
function filter_resources($phase,$wa,$aus,$topics){
  $resources = get_transient( 'yoursite_filtered_resources' );
  if(!$resources) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql =<<<SQL
SELECT
  t.slug,p.*
FROM
  wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID=tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND p.post_type = 'resources'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND t.term_id IN (%d,%d,%d,%d)
  AND CONCAT(tt.taxonomy,'/',t.term_id) IN (
    'phase-of-learning/%s',
    'wa-curriculum/%s',
    'australian-curriculum/%s',
    'topics/%s'
  )
GROUP BY
  p.ID
HAVING
  COUNT(*)=4
ORDER BY
  p.post_date DESC
SQL;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,
      $phase,$wa,$aus,$topics,  // For the %d replacements
      $phase,$wa,$aus,$topics   // For the %s replacements
    );
    $resources = $wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT);
    $hours = RESOURCE_CACHE_HOURS * 60 * 60;
    set_transient( 'yoursite_filtered_resources', $resources, $hours);
  }  
  return $resources;
}
```

### UPDATE

Here's another take on the code that is attempting to handle the cases where less than four criteria are selected by the user:

```
define('RESOURCE_CACHE_HOURS',4);
function filter_resources($phase,$wa,$aus,$topics){
  $resources = get_transient( 'yoursite_filtered_resources' );
  if(!$resources) {
    $terms = $taxterms = array();
    if (!empty($phase))
      $taxterms[$phase] = 'phase-of-learning/%s';
    if (!empty($wa)) 
      $taxterms[$wa] = 'wa-curriculum/%s';
    if (!empty($aus))
      $taxterms[$aus] = 'axustralian-curriculum/%s';
    if (!empty($topics))
      $taxterms[$topics] = 'topics/%s';
    $count = count($taxterms);
    $having = ($count==0 ? '' : "HAVING COUNT(*)={$count}");
    $values = array_keys(array_flip($tax_terms));
    $values = array_merge($values,$values);  // For %d and $s
    $taxterms =  implode("','",$taxterms);
    $terms = implode(',',array_fill(0,$count,'d%'));
    global $wpdb;
    $sql =<<<SQL
SELECT
  t.slug,p.*
FROM
  wp_posts p
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr ON p.ID=tr.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
WHERE 1=1
  AND p.post_type = 'resources'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  AND t.term_id IN ({$terms})
  AND CONCAT(tt.taxonomy,'/',t.term_id) IN ('{$taxterms}')
GROUP BY
  p.ID
{$having}
ORDER BY
  p.post_date DESC
SQL;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$values);
    $resources = $wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT);
    $hours = RESOURCE_CACHE_HOURS * 60 * 60;
    set_transient( 'yoursite_filtered_resources', $resources, $hours);
  }  
  return $resources;
}
```

Comment: +1 for query optimisation compared to the original question.

Comment: @Zack - Thanks. I hope it matches her needs. I couldn't really test it enough without building up relevant test data.

Comment: First, wow - thanks! I know it's hard without data :(
This returns results in my db tool in .391 seconds which is a bit faster and definitely more efficient... however I'm not sure how I could modify it to return results if only one, two or three of the terms were searched on. This is a screenshot of the "filter" box: [link]http://smoljak.com/filters.jpg - so you can see that if one of the taxonomies is left blank, it's not factored into the query. in my version I used php conditionals in the function to decide whether to include each section of SQL or not.

Comment: Also will look into the transients stuff... looks like it might be a good addition.

Comment: @goatlady - I added an update to address less than four terms searched; let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Someone gave me a down vote on this. If you are going to down vote, please give a reason.

Comment: Hi @MikeSchinkel - sorry I didn't respond with regards to the modified version, my client ended up changing some other things to do with the taxonomies and I have been busy with that, and haven't gone back to this yet. It looks great though, so thank you very much, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: @goatlady - Glad it helped!

Answer (score 6):

Unless you need to stay backwards compatible with WP 3.0, you can just take advantage of the [advanced taxonomy queries](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-1-advanced-taxonomy-queries/) support in WP 3.1.

The code that generates the SQL can be found in wp-includes/taxonomy.php

Comment: I hadn't heard about this - obviously the WP team are realising the need for easier querying now that they've added all the tasty custom taxonomy stuff. It does say at the bottom of that article however "Advanced taxonomy queries are cool, but be aware that complex queries are going to be slower" which makes me think I'd be better off with a custom SQL solution for this one.

Comment: Please also read the comments on that post. Bottom line is that you're unlikely to come up with a faster solution.

Comment: The built in advanced taxonomy queries solution is actually going to be gobs faster than anything else you can come up with. The joins its doing are optimized for speed, as it's just joining indexed integer tables together. It does do some pre-selecting first to get the values it needs to build those joins, but unlike your original solution, it's only doing one join per taxonomy instead of three for the final query.

Comment: @Otto - *"Gobs faster than anything else"*;  Bit of hyperbole, no?

Comment: @Otto - Just for the sidenote: I'm missing querying all posts in a taxonomy regardless of term somehow. Need to prefetch all IDs first to work around that. Additionally it's not possible to combine AND and OR and have grouping for those.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, use inner joins, not left joins. Left joins will force a query plan that scans the whole posts table until it find a matching post through your term filters.

Secondly, you can reduce the number of needed joins by pre-fetching the terms using get_term().

Combining the two, your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts posts
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termA
ON posts.ID = termA.object_id
AND termA.term_taxonomy_id = $termA_taxid
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termB
ON posts.ID = termB.object_id
AND termB.term_taxonomy_id = $termB_taxid
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termC
ON posts.ID = termC.object_id
AND termC.term_taxonomy_id = $termC_taxid
JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships termD
ON posts.ID = termD.object_id
AND termD.term_taxonomy_id = $termD_taxid
WHERE ...
```

Which should yield the same results with 5 joined tables instead of 13, and with a query plan that starts by looking up whichever posts tied to whichever term occurs the least frequently in term_relationships.

Comment: This is basically what Advanced Taxonomy Queries in 3.1 does, albeit in a more configurable and expandable fashion.